# Escaping mid-string percent signs, is a regex the best option?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to escape `%` characters in a string entered by the user - replacing them with `[%]` *unless* they are at the start or end of the string.

For example `%foo%foo[%]foo%` should become `%foo[%]foo[%]foo%`. Whitespace isn't a concern: this is all about escaping any mid-string percent signs.

A regular expression of `[^[]%[^\]]` will match the mid-string percentages, but also the adjacent characters (so `o%f` in my example).

Is there a reasonable regular expression that will match just the mid-string non-escaped percentage characters?

I am wondering if a non-regex solution would be preferable, such as

Iterating through the characters in the string, and building up a replacement string with the percentages escaped

```
const string TEST = "%foo%foo[%]foo%";

StringBuilder escaped = new StringBuilder();
escaped.Append(TEST[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < TEST.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (TEST[i] != '%' || (TEST[i - 1] == '[' && TEST[i] == '%' && TEST[i + 1] == ']'))
    {
        escaped.Append(TEST[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        escaped.Append("[%]");
    }
}

escaped.Append(TEST[TEST.Length - 1]);
```

-or-

Doing a three-pass token-based replacement such as

```
const string TOKEN = "!PERCENT!"; // a string which we hope(!) we will never encounter in the string we're escaping
const string TEST = "%foo%foo[%]foo%";

string escaped = TEST.Replace("[%]", TOKEN);
escaped = replaced.Replace("%", TOKEN);
escaped = replaced.Replace(TOKEN, "[%]");
```

(although this would also escape any first or last character percentages, which isn't what I want)

As for why I need to do this - I am escaping `Like` filter expression values entered by the user that are being applied to a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

```
(?<!^)((?<!\[)|(?!.\]))%(?!$)
```

It's a bit ugly because I wanted it match the cases foo[%foo and foo%]foo.

```
(?<!^) - Prevents match at start of string (negative look behind)
(?!$) - Prevents match at end of a string (negative look ahead)
(?<!\[)|(?!.\]) - Prevents a match if previous is '[' AND ']' is next.
```

You could use this with Regex command like:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!^)((?<!\[)|(?!.\]))%(?!$)", x => "[" + x + "]")
```

Comment: Thanks for supplementing your answer with a breakdown of what the parts of the regex mean.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to escape user-entered text that contains SQL wildcard characters, because you're going use the value as the target of a `LIKE` clause in a sql query, correct?

In which case, you've also got to look at

- `%` (match zero or more characters.
- `_` (match 1 character)
- [...] (match character set).
- [^...] (match character set).

Wouldn't it be easire just to prohibit users from entering wildcards in the first place?

Comment: Yes it would be easier, but this isn't an option in my scenario as the users need to able to specify percent signs in the filter value.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code sample:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace("%fooo[%foo%]foo[%]foo%", @"(?!^)(\[?%(?!\])|(?<!\[)%\]?)(?!$)", "[%]");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

it replaces % with [%] as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to do the trick:  `[^[](?<Token>%)[^]]`

`[^[]` means a character that does not match `[`

`(?<Token>%)` means a named capture group, "Token", that matches the `%`

`[^]]` means a character that does not match `]`

basicly the same as your regex, except the inner % is inside a named capture group so you can easily get its position.

Comment: I did think about using capture groups, but was not sure how to use them in a replace statement using the .NET regex class.

Comment: $group-name is how you would refer to a capture group in a replace op.  In this case:  `$Token`

Answer (score 0):

If you put the elements of the regex into brackets, you'll get a set of matching groups, which you can reference by number in the regex-replace function using.

You can then do a regex like `(.)(%)(.)` and get named groups `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`. You can then use `$1` and `$3` in your replacement string to put back the same characters as were there in the first place.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html for info on how to use named groups in regex replace. (it has specific info on .NET)

Hope that helps.

Comment: `.` wont work because it'll match on whitespace - which is not desired I believe.

Comment: I'm not concerned with whitespace, and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: `.` will match the  `[` and `]` characters as well, which I believe the op said was undesireable.

Comment: my point was about the use of brackets to form named groups, not about the contents of the brackets. The OP has already got a regex that matches the pattern he wants; I merely used the dots in my example to simplify it to make the use of the brackets clearer.

Comment: This will also fail with overlapping matches: `a%b%c` -> `a[%]b%c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w)%(\w)
```

Use this and then replace with `$1[%]$2`. That should do the trick. It'll match any `%` with a word character (basically alphanumeric) on both sides.

Comment: this doesnt work if there is a space (or whitespace) to either side of the %

Comment: right. that was my intent, but i read the question wrong and it has since been clarified.

Comment: This regex also matches the characters to the left and right of the `%`, which was the key issue with my original regex.